# How to pass object from main process to child process using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipc, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I try to use Multiprocessing in a class.I use Multiprocessing.pipe() to pass the instance o from parent process to child process.

```
        self.listofwritetags = self.collectwritetaglist()
        self.progressbar['value'] = 20
        self.frame.update_idletasks()
        self.alldevice = alldevices_V3.AllDevices(self.comm_object)
        self.progressbar['value'] = 40
        self.frame.update_idletasks()

        con1,con2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        con1.send(self.alldevice)
        con2.send(self.comm_object)        


        # Multithreading section
        # self.callmotor1dprocess = thread_with_trace(target=self.callallmotor1d,args=(self.comm_object,self.alldevice))
        self.callmotor1dprocess = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.callallmotor1d,args= (con1,con2))
        self.listofthread.append(self.callmotor1dprocess)



        self.button2.config(text="Initialized")
        initial = "True"
        self.progressbar.stop()
```

Now I call all Multiprocessing Initiate

```
def startprocess(self):
        for item in self.listofthread:
            item.start()
        self.button3.config(text="started")

   def stopprocess(self):
        for item in self.listofthread:
            item.kill()
```

This Code I call inside the class.Now Executed method I should call outside of the class.

```
def callallmotor1d(con1,con2):
comobject = con1.recv()
devices = con2.recv()
while True:
    Allmotorprocessing.process(comobject, devices)
```

But I got the error which is very common:-
Error message:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\misu01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 236, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\misu01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\misu01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 236, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\misu01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

I don't know why thread.lock object is created.
To avoid this error I try to modify my Alldevices class and comm_object class like this:-

Here is my modification:-

class AllDevices:

```
def __init__(self,comobject):
    self.mylock = threading.Lock()
    self.comobject = comobject
    self.dfM1D = pd.read_excel(r'C:\OPCUA\Working_VF1_5.xls', sheet_name='Motor1D')
    self.allmotor1dobjects = callallmotor1D_V3.Cal_AllMotor1D(self.dfM1D, self.comobject)


def __getstate__(self):
    state = vars(self).copy()
    # Remove the unpicklable entries.
    del state['mylock']
    return state

def __setstate__(self, state):
    # Restore instance attributes.
    vars(self).update(state)
```

Here is the comobject class.

```
class General():
def __init__(self):
    self.client = Communication()
    self.mylock = threading.Lock()
    self.sta_con_plc = self.client.opc_client_connect()
    self.readgeneral = ReadGeneral(self.client.PLC)
    self.writegeneral = WriteGeneral(self.client.PLC)

def __getstate__(self):
    state = vars(self).copy()
    # Remove the unpicklable entries.
    del state['mylock']
    return state

def __setstate__(self, state):
    # Restore instance attributes.
    vars(self).update(state)
```

But still I got an error.

Is this my implementation is correct?

```
self.allmotor1dobjects = callallmotor1D_V2.Cal_AllMotor1D(self.dfM1D, self.comobject,self.logger)
```

Here self.allmotor1dobjects is also class instances.

like:-

```
    self.client = Communication()        
    self.readgeneral = ReadGeneral(self.client.PLC)
    self.writegeneral = WriteGeneral(self.client.PLC)
```

These are also class instances.

I never used thread.lock any of these two classes.
I don't know how it is created.

As per the docs suggested https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances
If I use **getstate** and **setstate**, it should remove this error.

In my case it doesn't work.

How can I remove this error.

any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: What is `devices`? Seems like they contain thread locks as attributes, which can't be pickled.

Comment: devices is a class object......class name is alldevices which is resonsible to initilize some basic configuration stuff.So I can't pass object of a class through pipe

Comment: Normally you can, but not if they have unpicklable instance attributes and haven't overridden the pickling behavior to avoid pickling them. I've posted an answer with some possible fixes, but without knowing anything about `alldevice` or your specific use case, I can't give a specific answer.

Comment: @SM2019 the problem isn't that your object is a "class object" (it is not, that implies that it is a class, you mean an *instance* of a class, but *everything* is an instance of a class in Python). The problem is that your object cannot be pickled.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga , thank you I understand now.

Comment: @ ShadowRanger, I try to implement what you have suggested but still no sucess.If my alldevices class contains also contains instance of classes, that could be also caused the problem.Like self.allmotor1dobjects,self.allsov1sobjects.I put overview of alldevice in answare section.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass *most* classes through a pipe, but not if the instances have attributes that are unpicklable types. In this case, the instances of `alldevice` (the instances of which are stored in some collection you stored as `self.devices`) have, directly or indirectly, a `threading.Lock` attribute (the error message says `_thread.lock` because under all the abstraction, that's the actually class that `threading.Lock` returns an instance of).

`threading.Lock` isn't picklable (because thread locks only make sense within a given process; even if you recreated them in another process, they wouldn't actually provide any sort of synchronization between the processes).

If the `alldevice` class is under your control, you have a few options:

1. Remove the per-instance `threading.Lock` if possible (easiest solution, but assumes synchronization isn't required, or that synchronization could be done by a shared global lock)
2. If synchronization is required, and must operate across processes, but needn't be per-instance, and you're on a UNIX-like system (Linux, BSD) you could use a shared global `multiprocessing.Lock()` instead; it will be inherited when the `Process` call triggers a `fork`
3. If synchronization is required, and you must have a per-instance `Lock` (and it's okay for the lock to operate across processes), you can replace `threading.Lock` with a pickle-friendly `multiprocessing.Manager`'s `Lock`. You'd need to make a common `multiprocessing.Manager()` instance somewhere (e.g. globally, or as a class attribute of `alldevice`), then use `Lock` from that manager instead of from `threading`. Simple example:

   ```
   import multiprocessing

   class alldevice:
       MANAGER = multiprocessing.Manager()  # Shared manager for all alldevice instances

       def __init__(self, ... other args here ...):
           self.mylock = self.MANAGER.Lock()  # Make picklable lock
           # ... rest of initialization ...
   ```

   When `multiprocessing` isn't involved, this will be slower than a `threading.Lock`, as it will require IPC to lock and unlock the lock (the `Manager`'s `Lock` instances are actually a proxy object that communicates with the `Manager` on whatever process it's actually running in), and it will lock across processes (probably for the best if you're locking access to actual hardware that can't be used concurrently from multiple processes), but it's relatively simple.
4. If synchronization is required, but only within a process, not across processes, you can take control of the pickling process to avoid trying to pickle the `threading.Lock`, and instead recreate it when it's unpickled on the other side. Just explicitly implement [the pickle support methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) to avoid pickling the `Lock`, and force it to be recreated on the other side. Example:

   ```
   import copy

   class alldevice:
       def __init__(self, ... other args here ...):
           self.mylock = threading.Lock()  # Use regular lock
           # ... rest of initialization ...

       def __getstate__(self):
           state = vars(self).copy()  # Make copy of instance dict
           del state['mylock']        # Remove lock attribute
           return state

       def __setstate__(self, state):
           vars(self).update(state)
           self.mylock = threading.Lock()  # Make new lock on other side

       # If you ever make copies within the same thread, you may want to define
       # __deepcopy__ so the local copy process doesn't make a new lock:
       def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
           # Make new empty instance without invoking __init__
           newself = self.__class__.__new__(self.__class__)
           # Individually deepcopy attributes *except* mylock, which we alias
           for name, value in vars(self).items():
               # Cascading deepcopy for all other attributes
               if name != 'mylock':
                   value = copy.deepcopy(value, memo)
               setattr(newself, name, value)
           return newself
   ```

   The `__deepcopy__` override is only needed if you want the copy to continue sharing the lock; otherwise, if a deep copy should behave as an entirely independent instance, you can omit it, and you'll end up with an unrelated lock in the copy.

If you don't have control of the `alldevice` class, but can identify the problematic attribute, your only option is to register a `copyreg` handler for `alldevice` to do the same basic thing as option #4, which would look something like this:

```
import copyreg

def unpickle_alldevice(state):
    self = alldevice.__new__(alldevice)  # Make empty alldevice
    vars(self).update(state)             # Update with provided state
    self.mylock = threading.Lock()       # Make fresh lock
    return self        

def pickle_alldevice(ad):
    state = vars(ad).copy()  # Make shallow copy of instance dict
    del state['mylock']      # Remove lock attribute
    return unpickle_alldevice, (state,)  # Return __reduce__ style info for reconstruction

# Register alternate pickler for alldevice
copyreg.pickle(alldevice, pickle_alldevice)
```

Comment: What I found today logger creates the problem.Actually it creats the thread.lock().I Used logger to log the event during  child process.The __getstate__ and __setsate__ should take care of this.